# Ruby on Rails - right way to take form input and insert it into the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this form:

```
= form_for([:mobile,@disclosure], :html => {:id => "disclosure-form", :remote => true}) do |f|
      %p
        =f.label :display_as, (t :select_disclosure_type)
        =f.select :display_as, options_from_collection_for_select(Disclosure.basics, :display_as,
          :name, f.object.display_as)
      %p
        =f.label :notes, (t :notes)
        =f.text_area :notes, :class => "#{validation_rules(:free_disclosure_notes)}", :rows => 5 , :id => "disclosure_notes_entry"
        = buttonset({:submit_label => (t "buttons.influencers.disclosures.create"),:submit_css_class => "call-to-action",
          :cancel_url => "#",:direction => :left_to_right})
```

and I have this controller so far:

```
  def create
    Rails.logger.debug "-"*100
    Rails.logger.debug session.inspect
    Rails.logger.debug "-"*100

    provider = nil

    @disclosure = params[:disclosure-form].blank?
    resource = build_resource({})

    begin
      if disclosure.nil?
        print "hello 1"
      else
          print "hello 2"
      end

    rescue Exception => ex
      Rails.logger.debug ex

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{}

    end
  end
```

But I am not sure how to get the @disclosures object to be populated so that I can insert it into the database?

How do I get the right data out of the form and add it to the database?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form data should be in `params[:disclosure]` hash. So, in your `create` action you would do something like:

```
def create
  @disclosure = Disclosure.new(params[:disclosure])

  if @disclosure.save
    # redirect to show or something else
  else
    # render 'new' for with validation errors
  end
end
```

This should save your object in DB. If there is no validation errors.

I'm not sure what this line does: `@disclosure = params[:disclosure-form].blank?`